# Why does part of my data go into the reducer directly without going into the combiner

Tags: hadoop, combiners

I am using version 0.20.0 of hadoop.

I have set the combiner class successfully. And my program runs successfully.

However, I found about 5% of my data didn't go into the combiner after coming out from the mapper, this data go into the reducer directly. I don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A note on the implementation of combiners in Hadoop: by default, the execution framework reserves the right
>   to use combiners at its discretion. **In reality, this means that a combiner may be invoked zero, one, or multiple
>   times.** In addition, combiners in Hadoop may actually be invoked in the reduce phase, i.e., after key-value pairs
>   have been copied over to the reducer, but before the user reducer code runs. As a result, combiners must be
>   carefully written so that they can be executed in these different environments.

You can find this in section 2.4 of the PDF below

[Data-Intensive Text Processing with MapReduce](http://lintool.github.com/MapReduceAlgorithms/MapReduce-book-final.pdf)